# special character in bigquery command line command

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that has column with some values of '\N' (without the quotes). I want to write a query with where clause on the field.
This is my command "SELECT barcode  FROM [mydataset1.mytab1] where barcode = '\N' and length(barcode) < 5"

The above command works perfectly on Windows. The above command returns records for which barcode is \N. Now the same command returns error on Linux platform. I think the special character needs to be written differently.
I tried "SELECT barcode  FROM [mydataset1.mytab1] where barcode = '/\N' and length(barcode) < 5" and this does not work either. Could you let me know who to modify the above query to work it on Linux environment?

I have attached the screenshots of the working and not working screens.
http://goo.gl/9p6cwD (Windows works)
http://goo.gl/DeAHij (Linux gives error)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `\\\`. For instance, this query works:

```
$ bq query "SELECT '\\\N';"
```